# Why pyinstaller can't compile python kivi code

Tags: python, compilation, pyinstaller, exe

[image: can't compile exe with pyinstaller from kivi python class]

Hello everybody, I would like to ask you why I can't compile kivi python class to exe file with pyinstaller. In fact it is compiled but exe does not run. It immediately exits the program. Please see attached picture from windows10 21h1.

Answer (score 0):

Si I found out this is a bug within pyistaller: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/6018 I tried to pip upgrade pyinstaller to 4.5.1 and my python win64 to 3.9.6 but no success, the problem persists.